# Type error using mout strftime

Tags: javascript

I'm using mout strftime to format dates.

However I get a Type error (undefined is not a function) whenever dates in the following format are passed to strftime. The format causing the error is dd/mm/yyyy and I'm wanting to convert using %d %b %y.

The code looks like this:

```
._strftime( new Date( data.date ), '%d %b %y' );
```

Could the original format be what's causing strftime to fail?

Comment: Is that a typo in the question or did you forget to surround the format with quotes? Like `._strftime( new Date( data.date ), 'd %b %y');`

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: Yes it's a typo. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using mout, which can't be changed.

Comment: My guess is the issue you are having is with data.date. What is data? can you show the code for data?

Comment: What's that dot symbol at `._strftime`? in JS variable names can't start with dot.

Comment: Data is a JSON object and the dot is from underscore

Comment: @webworker Why don't you try debug your code in Firebug or Firefox built-in debugger and see whats the problem?